# USB Power switch

Tags: arduino-nano, usb, arduino-leonardo

Can an Arduino power a USB device like a tablet from one of it's pins or do I need a relay? I want to essentially have the Arduino turn on and off a USB charger. Thanks

Comment: USB is 5V, not 3.3V. Also, no. 40mA is nowhere near enough for a typical USB device.

Comment: do not use an arduino as a power supply

Comment: Any advice on how to do this then? Thanks

Comment: use a mosfet instead of a relay; simpler, cheaper, lower power waste. google mosfet as a switch

Answer (score 2):

If you already have a 5V source then you can use a MOSFET as a switch to turn on/off the power to the tablet like this:
[image]

But if you want to turn on/off a USB charger that goes to an AC outlet, then you will need to control a relay to turn on/off the AC supply to the USB charger. You can use a relay module like this: [https://www.amazon.com/Tolako-Arduino-Indicator-Channel-Official/dp/B00VRUAHLE](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00VRUAHLE)

[image]